# Jenkinsfile and GitHub Enterprise pull request

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, github-enterprise

I'm recently working on Jenkins Pipeline.
I put the Jenkinsfile under the project root folder, and it looks like this:

```
+ project_root
 - src
 - Jenkinfile
```

In Jenkinfile, there are some stages defined, such as test, build and deploy.
What I want to do is to let the Jenkins automatically trigger the Pipeline job when a pull request is created(trying to use WebHook).

I have tried to use GitHub Organization Plugin, but the GitHub enterprise server can't return the JSON result as `https://api.github.com/` does. In fact, it returns, 404 Not Found. All RESTful APIs work fine, just the root access, `https://corporate.github.server/api/v3/`.

So the GitHub Organization Plugin raises an error for accessing the GitHub enterprise server APIs.

I wanna ask, is there another way to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Is the question how to trigger a build with that specific plugin on Jenkins, what is the correct API endpoint, or how to get webhooks on GitHub Enterprise to point to Jenkins?

Comment: Have a look at https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/